# LOWORD() receives DWORD (unsigned long) but WPARAM is UINT_PTR (unsigned int)

Tags: c++, c

As a long is wider than an int giving the low order of an unsigned long should return something bigger than just the low order of unsigned int.

Why does the function still know what the low order of the parameter is? Does it analyze the type given thus DWORD to be understood as a maximum in this case?

Comment: No one says that long "must" be larger than int (not smaller yes, but it can be the same too)

Comment: `As a long is wider than an int `  It is?  This compiles with no errors in VS 2010:  `int main() {static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), "ints and longs are not the same size"); }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It might be. It depends. OP stated that it is. So for this example that holds.

Answer (score 1):

LOWORD() does not receive a DWORD, it casts it to a **DWORD_PTR**.

Both **DWORD_PTR** and **UINT_PTR** have the same size.
(32 bit or 64 bit, depending on the operating system architecture).